# creating new map with the existing list

Tags: groovy

I have a list with values as below :

> ["HTC Magic":"Tetris.apk", "Motorola Droid Milestone":"TheSims3.apk",
>   "Acer C6":"TheSims3.apk"];

I would like to convert this list to a map which looks like

> [Tetris.apk:[HTC Magic], TheSims3.apk:[Motorola Droid Milestone, Acer
>   C6]]

Comment: Isn't that first thing a map too?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, came back to work after the holidays...will check your solution and will update you soon, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapIn = ["HTC Magic":"Tetris.apk", "Motorola Droid Milestone":"TheSims3.apk", "Acer C6":"TheSims3.apk"]
mapOut = [:].withDefault { [] }
mapIn.each { k, v -> mapOut[v] << k }
mapOut
> [Tetris.apk:[HTC Magic], TheSims3.apk:[Motorola Droid Milestone, Acer C6]]
```

If you don't mind the pattern abuse, you could use `inject`:

```
mapOut = mapIn.inject([:].withDefault {[]}) { m, k, v -> m[v] << k; m }
> [Tetris.apk:[HTC Magic], TheSims3.apk:[Motorola Droid Milestone, Acer C6]]
```

If you don't mind how you get the values out, you could use `groupEntriesBy`:

```
mapOut = mapIn.groupBy { it.value }
mapOut["TheSims3.apk"]*.key
> [Motorola Droid Milestone, Acer C6]
```